# rake:db seed issue with Catarse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, database-migration, seeding

I'm trying to clone the Catarse repository: [Git catarse](https://github.com/catarse/catarse)

and I get all the way to the end but once I try to run rake db:seed I get the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - /Users/'USERNAME'/Desktop/my_websites/crowdfund_test/catarse/tmp/cache/
/Users/'USERNAME'/Desktop/my_websites/crowdfund_test/catarse/db/seeds.rb:116:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

Do you know why??

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. Then I realized I did not have the directory

```
/yourPath/catarse/tmp/cache/
```

Once I created it, seeding worked just fine!